# Unable to install ffmpeg-php on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

When I searched for this error, it seems to be more common in CentOS but I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

My issue is that I've followed this installation on ffmpeg-php's site and I've ran into an error when doing this command.

```
./configure && make
```

The following error I recieve is

`checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for ffmpeg support... yes, shared
checking whether to force gd support in ffmpeg-php... no
checking for ffmpeg headers...
configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option`

How do I fix this? Some people said to just do ``` sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-dev`` or ```ffmpeg-devel` but neither have worked and it's getting frusterating that there's no solution for this right now. It's like I'm the only one having this issue.

And yes my FFMPEG is installed, if I type in ffmpeg -cmd then I receive data from ffmpeg. And I am able to encode a video so it IS installed.

Comment: ffmpeg-php is long dead and unmaintained since 2007; or at least upstream is. I don't see how it is possible to work with any supported version of `ffmpeg`. Are you sure you even need a PHP wrapper? See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, FFmpeg headers are distributed among several packages, which are built from the `ffmpeg` source package. I guess you should install all of them ([list here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/wily/ffmpeg)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavcodec-ffmpeg-dev libavdevice-dev libavdevice-ffmpeg-dev \
libavfilter-dev libavfilter-ffmpeg-dev libavformat-dev libavformat-ffmpeg-dev libavresample-dev \
libavresample-ffmpeg-dev libavutil-dev libavutil-ffmpeg-dev libpostproc-dev libpostproc-ffmpeg-dev \
libswresample-dev libswresample-ffmpeg-dev libswscale-dev libswscale-ffmpeg-dev
```

Comment: That did not fix my issue. I still get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Try installing [libavfilter-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libavfilter-dev) also. If it doesn't work, try installing every `-dev` package that is built from the `ffmpeg` source package ([list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/wily/ffmpeg)) .

Comment: Issue still remains :( I don't understand how codec files would relate to how I cannot install ffmpeg-php. Should be something directly with Ubuntu & FFMPEG don't you think?

Comment: @CameronSwyft, I edited my answer again. Could you try it?

Comment: Still same issue :(((

Comment: Weird. Could you post on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/) the contents of the `config.log` file?

Comment: If you can tell me where I can find this config.log file then yes I can :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36628/discussion-between-anderson-m-gomes-and-cameron-swyft).

Comment: The solution really did not work. All details are in the chat session.

Comment: The conclusion to this experience is, don't use something that hasn't been updated in over 6 years. :D